# iOS CoreBluetooth can't receive notifications in background

Tags: ios, swift, background, core-bluetooth

I am writing an app that should be able to connect to a Ble device and receive update for one of the characteristics.

I am able to discover the device I want to connect to, connect to it, and register for notifications on the characteristic I am interested in.

Every time the app receives an update for this characteristic it will send the value to a server via an http call.

Everything is working fine in the foreground but as soon as I background my app, it stops receiving the updates. I added

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>bluetooth-central</string>
    <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
</array>
```

to my plist file.
I am testing on an iPhone6 plus running iOS 9.3. Developing with Xcode 8 and swift 2.3. Notifications are being sent every 10 seconds by the Ble device but the app won't handle the notifications in the bakground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue.

I was instantiating the object taking care of all the scanning, connecting, reading, etc in my AppDelegate.
As soon as I moved it to a ViewController it started working just fine in the background. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add capabilities of Required background mode for Bluetooth in Project/capabilities
Since you are able to use the blue tooth while foreground, I believe you have added necessary entitlements